# Cronjob not executing file

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to setup a cronjob that allows a script to run every minute to check if any new rows have been added to a table in my database. If so - it will send a mail. It works fine when i execute it manually, but when i try to run it as a cronjob it doesn't work. I feel like i've tried everything including the recommendations from related stack posts.

my cronjob (that's not working) - added via root and the "crontab -e" command (i've also tried to add it to the /etc/crontab file):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/666f41556b/core/mailer.php
```

I've also tried to run this command in my cron file (and it works as it's supposed to):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/uptime > /tmp/uptime
```

When i run the command in my linux command line as root i get the following error (and every folder including mailer.php has file permission 755):

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/666f41556b/core/mailer.php
Could not open input file: /var/www/html/666f41556b/core/mailer.php
```

Comment: Look in `/var/mail/root` if you get error messages from cron and add them to your question, please.

Comment: What is the error output after replacing `/usr/bin/php` by `/usr/bin/head`? And what is the GNU/Linux distribution?

Comment: Are you sure the file is there at that path?